# VW Passat estate 2008 remote key won't lock doors

Tags: vw, passat, central-locking

I very recently a second hand VW Passat estate which is in really great condition and low millage for a real bargain price. This was because the key fob doesn't remotely lock the doors AND the little plastic emergency key to manually lock them has been lost.

I'm now looking to see if I can fix this myself or if it will need to go to a dealership. Hoping someone  might have some knowledge in the area as everything I have found requires you to have the emergency key or another key that's already working.

As it stands I have two key fobs

1. Is programmed to the car and will start the car just fine when I insert it into the starter port. BUT won't unlock/lock the doors/boot. Its plastic key is missing
2. A never used fob that isn't programmed to the car and just has a blank plastic key.

I first noticed that both fobs had dead batteries so these have been replaced. The little red light now turns on to indicate a button press.

The car also central locks fine when you are inside the car and press the lock button on the door, so I assume the central locking itself is working fine.

Question is, with the two above keys is there anyway to get fob 1 synced to lock/unlock the car. Fob 2 I assume will need to be programmed by a service centre but any advice on that would be good to.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to the site! What do you mean by the plastic key? I have driven a VW Passat mid-2000s model, and the plastic part is the remote, with the key itself being metal and non-removable, i.e. the metal key can't be lost (without losing the entire plastic remote, that is). The metal key should lock the doors if used on the mechanical door lock.

Comment: Afetr replacing the keyfob batteries, did you re-code the fobs to the car?

Comment: @juhist hi, I have a fob which is inserted into the dash to start the car. There is a small plastic emergency key. It looks like https://www.ebay.co.uk/i/132538373706?chn=ps

Comment: @SolarMike I have not, as far as I could find you need a working key to re-code? This is really my question

Comment: Ah, yes, now I remember. The newer Passat has that kind of fob.